# Average order of the prime counting function

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics

I am very interested in the *average order* of arithmetic functions. The average order of the prime counting function is
$$\overline{\pi}(n):=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\pi(k)$$
I wanted an asymptotic formula for this function (it is very probable that a closed form might not exist).  Here is what I did: I could not do anything with the sum, so I derived an approximation. First, I changed this sum to
$$\frac1n+\frac1n\sum_{2<k\le n}\frac k{\log k}$$
(this is an approximation). Now I used the Euler summation method, and some other techniques to simplify this to
$$\overline{\pi}(n)\approx\frac1n+\frac1n\left(\frac2{\log 2}+\mathrm{Ei}(2\log n)-\mathrm{Ei}(\log 4)-O\left(\frac n{\log n} \right)\right)\quad\text{ for sufficiently large }n$$
where $\mathrm{Ei}$ is the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). My question is: is there a better formula? if so, please mention a proof of it.

Comment: take into account that $\lim\pi(n)\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)=1$ but $\lim\pi(n)-\frac{n}{\log(n)}\neq 0$ so I don't know if that approximation will prove useful here

Comment: @MatíasUres yes, it not a very good approximation, but it still is; if we take the ratio of the average order and the approximation at $n=10000$, the answer is approx. 1.13756, which is close to 1. I mentioned it is an approximation, not asymptotic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the PNT stating that $\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}(1+o(1))$ which gives that $$\frac1{x}\sum_{n\le x} \pi(n) = \frac1{x}\sum_{n\le x} \frac{n}{\log n}(1+o(1))= \frac1{x}(1+o(1))\sum_{n\le x} \frac{n}{\log n}$$ $$=\frac1{x}(1+o(1)) \frac{x^2}{2\log x}(1+o(1))=\frac{x}{2\log x}(1+o(1))$$

Note that it is not immediate that $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{n}{\log n}o(1)=o(1)\sum_{n\le x} \frac{n}{\log n}$, it holds because $\frac{n}{\log n}$ is non-negative and $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{n}{\log n}\to \infty$